# Shadow & Opacity In css3 For IE8 (Not Match)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, opacity, css

i have some images (in front of my bachground-image) with low opacity(png format)
and every thing was good in ie8 & firefox until i add pie.htc(or border-radious.htc from google code) for rounded corners & Shadow Box in ie8...

after adding pie.htc by :

```
behaviour : url(pie.htc);
```

and adding below codes :

```
border-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius:15px;
-webkit-border-radius:15px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px red;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px red;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px red;
```

the opacity of my images has gone...

i test it with a simple html project and figured out when we use shadow box in ie 8(just ie8 & ff is ok) the shadow fills our entire element , so the opacity is wanished.

how can i fix this shadow + opacity  problem?

=====================================================

MY QUESTION IN ONOTHER WAY :

HOW CAN WE COMBINE THE BELOW CODES FOR IE8 (with keeping opacity):

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=25)";//opacity
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=25);//opacity

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(attribute1=value1, attribute2=value2, etc)";//shadow
```

thanks in advance

Comment: hi my dear friends / i edited my question / thanks for future helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems it's not possible to use shadow with opacity In IE 8...
When You add shadow after opacity to an element (in firefox every thing is ok) in IE8 you can not feel Opacity exists , because of that shadow fills the entire element and do n't let the opacity show itself.

however i checked this issue by the simple html project and searched for solving this issue with no results / if you find a solution about this plz share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

icant is correct but has a small typo. It should be progid instead of profid. I tried editing but it wouldn't let me edit just one letter.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=25) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(attribute1=value1, attribute2=value2, etc);
```

Thanks icant!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the shadow after the opacity and add a space in-between. It's as simple as it could be.

```
filter: profid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=25) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(attribute1=value1, attribute2=value2, etc);
```